# D3DX11d_43.dll is reported missing, but it's in current directory AND system32

Tags: visual-studio-2010, direct3d

Trying to run D3D samples from the DX11Jun20 SDK, I get the typical "D3DX10d_43.dll is missing" error that people get when linking to debug D3D but that do not have the DLL installed.

The part that confuses me is that I have copied it from the SDK to the local folder alongside the tutorial.exe file, and there's already a copy in System32 anyway!

What else could I have wrong that it being in both of those two places doesnt allow the app to run when linked to debug D3D11 like this?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Hmm, are you reading it correctly?  You'd have D3DX10_43.dll, no "d".  And you'd normally have it in syswow64, not system32.  Beware of any dependencies that might be missing as well.

Comment: Remember if your system is x64 native that there are two different ``D3DX10_43d.DLL``. If your app is 32-bit, it needs the one in ``%WINDIR%\SysWow64``

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the *DirectX End-User Runtime* for the debug version of the dynamic libraries. The installer is downloadable from here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35